# How to explain "Vacuum Cleaner Effect" for upper level PV anomaly?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, meteorology

Recently I asked a question regarding PV Anomalies in Earth Science Stack Exchange:
https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/25478/how-to-explain-vacuum-cleaner-effect-for-upper-level-pv-anomaly

I don't know in which forum the question is better placed: on the one hand it's about meteorology (earth science), on the other hand it's about fluid dynamics and better related to this forum...

I don't want to make a copy of the question here - therefore the link - I apologize.